# What’s the active form of "My jacket was made in Thailand"?

Tags: active-vs-passive

What’s the active form of "My jacket was made in Thailand"?

When we normally change the sentence into active voice, we get:

> They made my jacket in Thailand

or so. But I think "made" is a general word. It doesn’t actually qualify for what it was made. So to be particular can I use other verbs instead of "made" in the active voice? Or what are other appropriate ways of transforming this sentence into active voice? Would you please give me similar equivalent form of active voice or other different ways of changing into active voice?

Comment: You might get better advice on [ell.se]

Comment: Would you please suggest similar equivalent?

Comment: You have the same problem with the original.  Not sure what the “or so” is doing there.  Make is a perfectly good verb to use for how a jacket comes into being.  To qualify the purpose for which a jacket was made you might say They made this jacket to keep the wearer warm in cold weather.  But that answers ***why*** and is completely different that saying ***where*** it was made.

Comment: Child laborers made my jacket in Thailand.

Comment: Since you don't care who tailored or produced the jacket, other than the country of origin, the passive voice serves well here. However, if you're set on active voice, you have to come up with the agent (the doer) yourself: They made my jacket in Thailand. A Thai factory made this jacket. It looks like some fine tailors put together this jacket. Leather workers in Thailand stitched this beauty.

Comment: _`Indef` made my jacket in Thailand._ The English pronoun `Indef` refers to some indefinite actor or thing not named in an utterance, but present nonetheless, often as subject for a passive construction. `Indef`, like the apostrophe, is never pronounced. Unlike the apostrophe, it is also never written, except by those who have learned its secret name by long study of gramarye.

Answer (score 3):

Passive:

> My jacket was made in Thailand.

Active:

> (Somebody) made my jacket in Thailand.

There is nothing special about “made”, jackets or Thailand here. They all convert between active and passive just fine.

The issue with converting to active voice is that we don’t know *who* made the jacket. This is one of the main reasons for using passive voice in the first place, after all: we either don’t know, don’t care or don’t want to say who the doer was.